# Calculating anniversaries of employees with their joining dates

Tags: mysql, sql

As part of database testing, we are to verify if the data is correctly rendered onto the webpage from database.

We have a table called 'emp_details' which stores employee details. We store joining date of an employee in it. Now, using this joining date field, I need to get a list all the employees who have a start date or anniversary date within the last ten days.

I tried various combinations of DATEDIFF() in MySQL but did not succeed.

The format on the webpage would look like this:

```
Name       Start Date        Years
----------------------------------
William    07/25/2004          8
Gordon     07/22/2007          5
Jill       07/26/2009          3
```

Could anyone please help me with the query for MySQL DB.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select * from 
employees where 
    dayofyear(`start date`) between dayofyear(curdate())-10 and dayofyear(curdate())
```

Comment: Thanks Podiluska. It worked fine. I have modified it to get the count of years: `select Name,start_date, year(curdate())-year(start_date) as No_Of_Years from emp
where dayofyear(start_date) between dayofyear(curdate())-10 and dayofyear(curdate())`

Answer (score 0):

You can use following in `WHERE` clause

```
DAYOFYEAR(CURDATE()) - DAYOFYEAR(start_date) < 10
```

OR is greater than (365 - 10)